# Cider with youngs wine yeast

Tags: yeast, cider

I have made some cider from Apple juice and some mixed fruit juice to try and mimic something like a mixed fruit copperberg. I used youngs super wine yeast and no additional sugar so that the aim would be 5.5%.

When it finished, it was closer to 7% and taste more like wine than cider.

Is there something I could have missed, or do I need a particular type of yeast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wine yeasts will eat up almost every sugar there is driving cider gravity often to below 1.000sg. Trick is to stop the fermentaion, backsweeten, or use a less alcohol tolerant yeast. Good ole rapid rise bread yeast does great low gravity cider.

Comment: doesnt bread yeast make the cider taste, bready? this is just something i have ready, not sure how accurate it is

Comment: I think this is a misconception. Many brewing yeasts smell like bread dough in starter or while hydrating. I think it's just what we associate the smell with since it was probably your first imprint of yeast in your senses. "Bread" aroma in beer is generally from malts. I've not experienced a bread character in cider.

Answer (score 0):

Apple juice contains a simple sugar and tends to ferment completely.

Some people add a non-fermentable sugar like lactose or even an artificial sweetener.

Some people add dry malt extract because it doesn't ferment as completely as apple juice.

Nottingham yeast is what I found I like the most.  It finishes around 1.004.  S-04 is another ale yeast recommended for cider.

Carbonation adds to the taste.  If you didn't carbonate or it was light you can try more carbonation to see if you prefer that.

Other things you can add include acid to make it sharper and tannins to give it a a puckering aftertaste.  Homebrew stores sell powders of both.  I've added strong black tea for tannins and was happy with it

Tannins take a while to age.  I feel cider tastes better a few months after bottling compared to a couple weeks.